# Unexpected NULLs in outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 3 tables I'm trying to join.  Let's call them TableA, TableB, and TableC:

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE
(
    Key1 int,
    PRIMARY KEY
    (
        Key1
    )
)
DECLARE @TableB TABLE
(
    Key1 int,
    Key2 int,
    PRIMARY KEY
    (
        Key1,
        Key2
    )
)
DECLARE @TableC TABLE
(
    Key3 int NOT NULL,
    Key1 int NOT NULL,
    Key2 int NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY
    (
        Key3
    )
)
```

Here's some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO @TableA (Key1) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO @TableB (Key1, Key2) VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)
INSERT INTO @TableC (Key3, Key1, Key2) VALUES (1, 1, NULL), (2, 1, NULL), (3, 1, 1), (4, 1, 3)
```

TableB and TableC both have foreign keys to TableA via Key1.  In practice, TableC can also refer to TableB via Key1 and Key2 combined, if Key2 is not null, but there's no actual foreign key.  Key3 is irrelevant, other than the fact that Key1 and Key2 are not part of the primary key of TableC.

I'm trying to write a query which combines TableB and TableC:

```
SELECT
    TableA.Key1 AS [A1],
    TableB.Key1 AS [B1],
    TableB.Key2 AS [B2],
    TableC.Key1 AS [C1],
    TableC.Key2 AS [C2],
    TableC.Key3 AS [C3]
FROM @TableA AS TableA
FULL OUTER JOIN @TableC AS TableC
    ON TableC.Key1 = TableA.Key1
FULL OUTER JOIN @TableB AS TableB
    ON (TableB.Key1 = TableA.Key1 AND TableC.Key1 IS NULL)
    OR (TableC.Key1 = TableB.Key1 AND TableC.Key2 = TableB.Key2)
WHERE (TableA.Key1 = TableB.Key1 OR TableA.Key1 = TableC.Key1)
ORDER BY TableB.Key2, TableC.Key2
```

My expectation is that TableB and TableC should both include all their rows, matching up the ones that match on both keys, and NULLS where they don't match.

I expect to get this:

```
A1       B1       B2       C1       C2      C3
1        NULL     NULL     1        NULL    1
1        NULL     NULL     1        NULL    2
1        1        1        1        1       3
1        1        2        NULL     NULL    NULL -- THIS ROW IS MISSING
1        1        3        1        3       4
1        1        4        NULL     NULL    NULL -- THIS ROW IS MISSING
```

But instead I get this:

```
A1       B1       B2       C1       C2      C3
1        NULL     NULL     1        NULL    1
1        NULL     NULL     1        NULL    2
1        1        1        1        1       3
1        1        3        1        3       4
```

If I comment out the WHERE clause, I get all the rows I expect, except A1 is NULL for the missing rows:

```
A1       B1       B2       C1       C2      C3
1        NULL     NULL     1        NULL    1
1        NULL     NULL     1        NULL    2
1        1        1        1        1       3
NULL     1        2        NULL     NULL    NULL   -- A1 should be 1
1        1        3        1        3       4
NULL     1        4        NULL     NULL    NULL   -- A1 should be 1
```

Why is TableA.Key1 coming back NULL and causing it to exclude rows where TableB.Key2 is missing?

EDIT:

Here's the final fixed query after I learned what I was doing wrong:

```
SELECT
    TableA.Key1 AS A1,
    Subquery.*
FROM @TableA AS TableA
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        TableB.Key1 AS [B1],
        TableB.Key2 AS [B2],
        TableC.Key1 AS [C1],
        TableC.Key2 AS [C2],
        TableC.Key3 AS [C3]
    FROM @TableC AS TableC
    FULL OUTER JOIN @TableB AS TableB
        ON TableB.Key1 = TableC.Key1 AND TableB.Key2 = TableC.Key2
) AS Subquery 
    ON Subquery.B1 = TableA.Key1 OR Subquery.C1 = TableA.Key1
ORDER BY Subquery.B2, Subquery.C2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is TableA.Key1 coming back NULL and causing it to exclude rows
>   where TableB.Key2 is missing?

A full outer join is the same as an `INNER JOIN` but any unmatched rows from either side are added back in with `NULL` for the columns from the other side.

Your query does full outer join of `A` and `C` first so start by looking at the result of that.

```
SELECT
    TableA.Key1 AS [A1],
    TableC.Key1 AS [C1],
    TableC.Key2 AS [C2],
    TableC.Key3 AS [C3]
FROM @TableA AS TableA
FULL OUTER JOIN @TableC AS TableC
    ON TableC.Key1 = TableA.Key1
```

This returns the following virtual table (VT1) going on to the next stage. As this is the same result as `INNER JOIN` I doubt it needs any explanation. Every row in `@TableC` successfully matched the single row in `@TableA`.

```
+----+----+------+----+
| A1 | C1 |  C2  | C3 |
+----+----+------+----+
|  1 |  1 | NULL |  1 |
|  1 |  1 | NULL |  2 |
|  1 |  1 | 1    |  3 |
|  1 |  1 | 3    |  4 |
+----+----+------+----+
```

This is then full outer joined onto `B`. The contents of `B` are

```
+------+------+
| Key1 | Key2 |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    2 |
|    1 |    3 |
|    1 |    4 |
+------+------+
```

The `INNER JOIN` of those two result sets with predicate `ON (TableB.Key1 = [A1] AND [C1] IS NULL) OR ([C1] = TableB.Key1 AND [C2] = TableB.Key2)` returns only 2 rows.

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| A1 | B1 | B2 | C1 | C2 | C3 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  3 |
|  1 |  1 |  3 |  1 |  3 |  4 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Unmatched rows from `VT1` are added back in as per `LEFT JOIN` (these are the ones where `C3` is `1` or `2`)

```
+----+------+------+----+------+----+
| A1 |  B1  |  B2  | C1 |  C2  | C3 |
+----+------+------+----+------+----+
|  1 | NULL | NULL |  1 | NULL |  1 |
|  1 | NULL | NULL |  1 | NULL |  2 |
|  1 | 1    | 1    |  1 | 1    |  3 |
|  1 | 1    | 3    |  1 | 3    |  4 |
+----+------+------+----+------+----+
```

and unmatched rows from `B` as per `RIGHT JOIN` (these were the ones where `B2` is `2` or `4`)

giving you the final result

```
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|  A1  |  B1  |  B2  |  C1  |  C2  |  C3  |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 1    | NULL | NULL | 1    | NULL | 1    |
| 1    | NULL | NULL | 1    | NULL | 2    |
| 1    | 1    | 1    | 1    | 1    | 3    |
| 1    | 1    | 3    | 1    | 3    | 4    |
| NULL | 1    | 2    | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | 1    | 4    | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: You explain why it does what it does but you don't say how to get what he wants.

Comment: @Hogan - I only see one question in the question. Which is `Why is TableA.Key1 coming back NULL and causing it to exclude rows where TableB.Key2 is missing?` - if OP understands why their current join doesn't work as they want they can apply that knowledge to fix it. Better to teach to fish then give the fish

Comment: Thanks, because of your help I see what's wrong with my query.  In summary: TableC joined with TableA will obviously never be null in this situation, so OUTER JOIN against the composite of those two will force the whole left side to be NULL for the non-matching rows in TableB.

Comment: @MartinSmith -- ok point taken -- I read it as -- make my query return the results I expect not these.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want -- note... you want a full outter on B and C so A does not matter -- don't even really need it in the query with your example, but you can left or inner join it as you wish (I used left join)

```
SELECT
  TableA.Key1 AS [A1],  -- Probably not needed
  TableB.Key1 AS [B1],
  TableB.Key2 AS [B2],
  TableC.Key1 AS [C1],
  TableC.Key2 AS [C2],
  TableC.Key3 AS [C3]
FROM @TableB AS TableB
FULL OUTER JOIN @TableC AS TableC ON TableB.Key1 = TableC.Key1 and TableB.Key2 = TableC.Key2
LEFT JOIN @TableA AS TableA ON TableB.Key1 = TableA.Key1 -- Probably not needed
```

Comment: TableA matters because in the real situation there are other columns in TableA that are also coming back null.  I suppose I should edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: @BryceWagner -- I figured -- that is why I said "Probably".   So this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
a.Key1 AS [A1],
b.Key1 AS [B1],
b.Key2 AS [B2],
c.Key1 AS [C1],
c.Key2 AS [C2],
c.Key3 AS [C3]
FROM @TableB b
LEFT JOIN @TableC c
    ON c.Key2 = b.Key2
INNER JOIN @TableA a
    ON b.Key1 = a.Key1

UNION

SELECT 
    a.Key1 AS [A1],
    b.Key1 AS [B1],
    b.Key2 AS [B2],
    c.Key1 AS [C1],
    c.Key2 AS [C2],
    c.Key3 AS [C3]
FROM @TableC c
LEFT JOIN @TableB b
    ON c.Key2 = b.Key2
INNER JOIN @TableA a
    ON c.Key1 = a.Key1
```

Output:

```
A1  B1  B2  C1  C2  C3
1   NULL    NULL    1   NULL    1
1   NULL    NULL    1   NULL    2
1   1   1   1   1   3
1   1   2   NULL    NULL    NULL
1   1   3   1   3   4
1   1   4   NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I got the B side first, and then get the C side and used a union to pull them together.

Hopefully this helps you...

Comment: Yeah, I considered using a UNION, but that would be a huge mess given how complex the real query is.  Not impossible, but not something I would want to maintain.  Martin Smith's answer actually helped me understand what is really going on so I can do it right.